# How to make input with unique rule in mutation scheme?

Tags: laravel, graph, laravel-lighthouse

I have input with unique rule:

```
input VoteCategoryInput {
    name: String! @rules(apply: ["string", "min:2", "max:255", "unique:vote_categories,name"]),
    active: Boolean!,
    in_subscriptions: Boolean!,
    meta_description: String,
    meta_keywords: [String],
}

extend type Mutation {
   createVoteCategory(
       input: VoteCategoryInput! @spread
   ): VoteCategory! @create

   updateVoteCategory(
       id: ID!,
       input: VoteCategoryInput! @spread
   ): VoteCategory! @update

   deleteVoteCategory(id: ID! @whereKey): VoteCategory @delete
}
```

and running mutation for existing rows = 10:

```
  mutation {
    updateVoteCategory(
      id: 10
      input: {
        name: "UPDATED Vote Category 11"
        active: false
        in_subscriptions: false
        meta_keywords: ["meta_keywords UPDATED 1", "meta_keywords UPDATED2"]
      }
    ) {
        id
        name
        slug
        in_subscriptions
        meta_description
        meta_keywords
        created_at
       updated_at
    }
  }
```

I got error with unique rule break : in checking sql tracement   I do not see condition id <> 10 - so this checking statement find itself.
I tried to put unique rule out of input :

```
input VoteCategoryInput {
    active: Boolean!,
    in_subscriptions: Boolean!,
    meta_description: String,
    meta_keywords: [String],
}

extend type Mutation {
   createVoteCategory(
       name: String! @rules(apply: ["string", "min:2", "max:255", "unique:vote_categories,name"]),
       input: VoteCategoryInput! @spread
   ): VoteCategory! @create

   updateVoteCategory(
       id: ID!,
       name: String! @rules(apply: ["string", "min:2", "max:255"]),
       input: VoteCategoryInput! @spread
   ): VoteCategory! @update

   deleteVoteCategory(id: ID! @whereKey): VoteCategory @delete
}
```

and with mutation :

```
  mutation {
    updateVoteCategory(
      id: 10
      name: "Vote Category name #8"
      input: {
        active: false
        in_subscriptions: false
        meta_keywords: ["meta_keywords UPDATED 1", "meta_keywords UPDATED2"]
      }
    ) {
        id
        name
        slug
        in_subscriptions
        meta_description
        meta_keywords
        created_at
       updated_at
    }
  }
```

But Now I got

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation
```

if name "Vote Category name #8" was found with other id - this mutation did not use any unique check.

How cat it be fixed ? I would prefer 1st way with name rule inside of input...
I did not find any similar option in docs at https://lighthouse-php.com/6/api-reference/directives.html#rules

```
UPDATED # 1:
```

I cretated a new validator with command :

```
php artisan lighthouse:validator VoteCategoryInputValidator
```

and got php file app/GraphQL/Validators/VoteCategoryInputValidator.php in which I can fill rules and messages methods which I can fill as I do in laravel app.

Next I need to assign VoteCategoryInputValidator to my mutation and I tried to add line in grqph file in input block:

```
input VoteCategoryInput {
    name: String! @rules(apply: ["string", "min:2", "max:255", "unique:vote_categories,name"]),
    active: Boolean!,
    in_subscriptions: Boolean!,
    meta_description: String,
    meta_keywords: [String],
    @rules(apply: ["App\\GraphQL\\Validators\\VoteCategoryInputValidator"])
}
```

I found reference to it at docs https://lighthouse-php.com/6/security/validation.html#single-arguments
in “Custom Validation Rules” blocks

But I got error :

```
Object of class App\\GraphQL\\Validators\\VoteCategoryInputValidator could not be converted to string",
```

Is it invalid syntax ?

**UPDATED # 2:**

With syntax :

```
   updateVoteCategory(
       id: ID!,
       input: VoteCategoryInput! @spread
   ): VoteCategory!
    @validator(class: "app\\GraphQL\\Validators\\UpdateVoteCategoryValidator")
    @update
```

I return array of rules in UpdateVoteCategoryValidator, but now I get list of errors for all fields :

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Validation failed for the field [updateVoteCategory].",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "updateVoteCategory"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "validation": {
          "name": [
            "The name field is required."
          ],
          "active": [
            "The active field is required."
          ],
          "in_subscriptions": [
            "The in subscriptions field is required."
          ],
          "input.name": [
            "The input.name has already been taken."
          ]
        },
```

I suppose that is as I use input, but how can I use input  in UpdateVoteCategoryValidator ?

Comment: You can use the rule `'unique:table,name_column_to_check,id_to_ignore'` on the update send the ID, do a @validator to separate schema from validations. ask any help if wanted.

Comment: Or use the `Rule::unique('table', 'name_column_to_check')->ignore($vote->id),` as say in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique).

Comment: Could you, please, point to ignore option at https://lighthouse-php.com/ docs ?

Comment: I have pointed the doc link in a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the `@validator` like the [lighthouse docs](https://lighthouse-php.com/6/security/validation.html#validator-classes). In there is an example with `Rule::unique('users', 'name')->ignore($this->arg('id'), 'id');` on the `UpdateUserInputValidator`. With the `@rule` directive they don't have any example with unique and the ID as you want.

You access the validator key values with `$this->arg('key')`.

**schema**

```
input VoteCategoryInput {
    name: String!,
    active: Boolean!,
    in_subscriptions: Boolean!,
    meta_description: String,
    meta_keywords: [String],
}

extend type Mutation {
   createVoteCategory(
       input: VoteCategoryInput! @spread
   ): VoteCategory! 
       @validator(class: "App\\GraphQL\\Validators\\CreateVoteCategoryValidator")
       @create

   updateVoteCategory(
       id: ID!,
       input: VoteCategoryInput! @spread #if you use the @spread, you don't need to use the key 'input.field' on the validator class because will "flat" the input.
   ): VoteCategory! 
       @validator(class: "App\\GraphQL\\Validators\\UpdateVoteCategoryValidator")
       @update

   deleteVoteCategory(
       id: ID! @whereKey
   ): VoteCategory 
       @delete
}
```

The `UpdateVoteCategoryValidator` rules file:

```php
 public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                 'required',
             ],
            'name' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('vote_categories', 'name')->ignore($this->arg('id')), # add to the ignore() 2nd parameter if the field has a different name.
            ],
            'active' => [
                'required',
            ],
            'meta_description' => [
                'required',
            ],       
            'meta_keywords' => [
                'required',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

The `CreateVoteCategoryValidator` rules file:

```
 public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('vote_categories', 'name'),
            ],
            'active' => [
                'required',
            ],
            'meta_description' => [
                'required',
            ],       
            'meta_keywords' => [
                'required',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: pLEASE READ UPDATED # 1

Comment: @mstdmstd this isn't rules to use `@rule`, just do 2 validators `UpdateVoteCategoryValidator` and `CreateVoteCategoryValidator` (one has rules with id the other don't), on the `mutation updateVoteCategory` use the `@validator` with the path. Later will edit my answer for you.

Comment: I try your syntax but got error :    Nuwave\Lighthouse\Exceptions\SchemaSyntaxErrorException 

  Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "CreateVoteCategoryValidator", near: nput! @spread
    ): VoteCategory!
    @validator("CreateVoteCategoryValidator")
    ...

Comment: @mstdmstd
 put the path like: `@validator(class: "App\\GraphQL\\Validators\\CreateVoteCategoryValidator")`. Don't forget to use a valid path to the class.

Comment: @mstdmstd I have put on validation all keys as `required` now you need to change it to your solution. Note the `!` on graphql you should be able to pass `null` as value so isn't `required`. The `[]` means is `array` on validation.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what have I to change to fix error in UPDATED # 2

Comment: @mstdmstd you need to change your `rules()`